# what happens during context switch between two processes in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, multiprocessing

Let's say process `p1` is executing with its own address space(stack,heap,text). When context switch happens, i understand that all the current cpu registers are pushed into PCB before loading process `p2`. Then TLB is flushed and loaded with `p2` address mapping and starts executing with its own address spaces.
What i would like know is the state of `p1` address space. Will it be copied to disk and updates its page table before loading process `p2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specifics of a context switch depend upon the underlying hardware. However, context switches are basically the same, even among different system.

The mistake you have is " i understand that all the current cpu registers are pushed into stack before loading process p2". The registers are stored in an area of memory that is usually called the PROCESS CONTEXT BLOCK (or PCB) whose structure is defined by the processor. Most processors have instructions for loading and saving the process context (i.e., its registers) into this structure. In the case of Intel, this can require multiple instructions saving to multiple blocks because of all the different register sets (e.g. FPU, MMX).

The outgoing process does not have to be written to disk. It may paged out if the system needs more memory but it is possible that it could stay entirely in memory and be ready to execute.

A context switch is simply the exchange of one processor's saved register values for another's.

Comment: This is the kind of explanation i exactly wanted. Thanks.  Question on your comment "It may paged out if the system needs more memory but it is possible that it could stay entirely in memory" .  If i understand correctly,  p1 is now sleeping, p2 is executing, p1's address space is swapped out only if needed.   If swap out of p1 page happens, How does OS know that the swapping out page belongs to process p1 and how will it update the p1 page table.

Comment: The operating system maintains a database of free pages. When pages are removed from P1's working set they get added to the free pages. Updating the page table is part of the freeing process. Normally, the OS will leave the "freed" pages alone so that, if P1 needs them again and they have not been used, the pages can be made valid again by updating the page table without a read to disk. The OS pages out process so it knows who's page it is making available.

Comment: sorry i still don't get it completely. If  there are free pages, why can't OS use the free pages instead of swapping out p1's page. At any point of time, memory might hold pages of multiple processes. How can OS identify the owner of the page, just using physical memory address?

Comment: When the OS thinks it needs memory, the normal process is to identify processes that it can use to reduce their physical memory. Then it removes physical page frames and claims them. It doesn't say "I need 3 page frames. Find three pages to get rid of." It may get rid of more page frames than it actually does. It knows owner of the page because it is removing page frames from a process; not claiming page frames then trying to identify what process they belong to.

Comment: Sorry for asking repeated questions. But still there could be multiple process waiting in the queue. How does the OS identify the right process whose page is still in memory. Will it go through each process and check if  it's page is in memory?

Comment: The OS knows how many pages each process has in physical memory. The page frames are fungible. The OS never needs to find a specific page frame to free it. It just needs to go to targeted process and free some of its page frames.

Comment: Great. Thank you for clarification.,